# Is there a linear transformation T from $R^3$ into $R^2$ such that $T(1,-1,1)= (1,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)=(0,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is there a linear transformation T from $R^3$ into $R^2$ such that $T(1,-1,1)=
> (1,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)=(0,1)$?

I see that all that I need is to check that (1,-1,1) and (1,1,1) are a basis of $R^3$, I see that they are linearly independent, but how do I know it spans $R^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose $T(v_1) = (1,0)$ and $T(v_2) = (0,1)$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, we can find a third vector $v_3$ such that $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent and hence they span $\mathbb{R}^3$. We can assign a value for $T(v_3)$, for example let $T(v_3) = (0,0)$.

Now given any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can express them uniquely as $x=\sum_{i=1}^3 c_iv_i$ and we have $T(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3 c_iT(v_i)$

Comment: Hey, one extra question (sorry for that), if, let's say {$v_1,v_2,v_3$} is not linearly independent, can I assume there does not exist sucha linear transformation?

Comment: in that case, we have to be careful whether it is well defined. since they are linearly dependent we can find $\sum_{i=1}^3 c_iv_i = 0$, we have to check if we have $\sum_{i=1}^3 c_iT(v_i) = 0$. Suppose it is well defined, then such linear transformation exists. To define it explicitly, find a non-zero vector that wasn't in the span yet and define the value of transformation there and things reduced to earlier case.

Answer (score 0):

The range of $T$ certainly spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\{(1,-1,1), (1,1,1) \}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but this does not imply that those two vectors are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. A basis is a linearly independent set of maximal size and in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it must have three elements. What you can say about such a $T$ though is that it’s kernel must have dimension $1$ (by the dimension theorem or rank-nullity theorem or whatever other name you may have heard).

Answer (score 0):

$T$ must have a corresponding $2$ by $3$ matrix, say $A$. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be the columns of matrix $A$. Also let $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Then:

$$\begin{cases} a_1-a_2+a_3=e_1 \\ a_1+a_2+a_3=e_2 \end{cases}$$

This is a linear system of equations with **vector variables**. It can be solved using elimination and the usual linear algebra approaches can mostly still be applied. If the system is consistent then, we know there is a linear transformation that does the job. Since the coefficient matrix is onto, we know that must be the case.